# Question of chargining the battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charge

When a battery has electricity,we can see it as a VDC source,but i just wonder that when we charge the battery,is it necessary to make another circuit to charge the battery or just connect it with a VDC source?i mean that is the picture shwon correct?

[image]

Comment: Usually there's a maximum current before bad things happen, so you need to limit the current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that is not a general solution and may be risky.

That has no defined current limit or voltage limit or smart charge profile.

This is important to prevent battery damage or catastrophic failure.
e.g. minimize outgassing or self heating

Read

http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/all_about_chargers